# Change uiorientation and set image fullscreen iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, scrollview

I have created an iphone application where i used uiimageview.In view did load method i have created a scrollview with uiimageview ,uibutton, uilabel. an image is set in the imageview .
In Image touch evant i want to rotate the view an set the uiimage in the uimage view fullscreen. how can i do this.
plz help me .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

You have to change both frame and transform.

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
imageView.transformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```